# Center Column Content In Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a project using Bootstrap 4. I have a row that consists of three columns. My code looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 center-block">
    <div>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time center-text"></i><br />
      <h3>On Time</h3>
      <h4>Just for you</h4>                      
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 center-block">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star center-text"></i><br />
    <h3>Excellent Service</h3>
    <h4>When you need it</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 center-block">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart center-text"></i><br />
    <h3>We want to be your favorite</h3>
    <h4>Why not?</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to center the content within each column. However, all of the content is left-aligned and I do not know why. As the code shows, I'm using the `center-block` and `center-text` classes. Yet, they do not seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `text-center` class might be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `text-center` instead of `center-block`.

There is no default Bootstrap class such as `center-text` and the class needs to be used for the parent container, not along with any child element.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <div>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i><br />
      <h3>On Time</h3>
      <h4>Just for you</h4>                      
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i><br />
    <h3>Excellent Service</h3>
    <h4>When you need it</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i><br />
    <h3>We want to be your favorite</h3>
    <h4>Why not?</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```